# winJS data win bind innerText of span Renders the html tags

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

I have an app that needs to render the HTML tags like `<bold>abc<bold>`

but when I do `<span data-win-bind='innerText: newText'></span>`

then the output comes some thing like

`<bold>abc</bold>` instead of **abc** . what to do in order to achieve this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rendering here is being done wrong

Try binding `innerHTML` rather than `innerText`

InnerText retrieves and sets the content of the tag as plain text, whereas InnerHtml retrieves and sets the same content but in HTML format.

Here's a microsoft site with same discussion

[inner text and html](http://forums.asp.net/t/1007826.aspx)

go through it :)